# MySQL: How can I delete two rows in a junction table based on a specific ID?

Tags: mysql, delete-row, junction-table

I have a Mysql junction table user_connections which maps the users table with the following columns: user_from and user_to, both are foreign keys in users table. user_from and user_to are both primary keys therfore a parttern like (1,2) and (1,2) can never repete.

**user_connections table.**

```
create table user_connections (
  user_from int,
  user_to int,
  primary key(user_from, user_to)
  );
  
  insert into user_connections(user_from, user_to) values(1, 2);
  insert into user_connections(user_from, user_to) values(2, 1);
  insert into user_connections(user_from, user_to) values(67, 1);
  insert into user_connections(user_from, user_to) values(68, 1);
  insert into user_connections(user_from, user_to) values(69, 1);
  insert into user_connections(user_from, user_to) values(70, 1);
```

**How it looks after insertion**

**Query #1**

```
select * from user_connections;
```

| user_from | user_to |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 67 | 1 |
| 68 | 1 |
| 69 | 1 |
| 70 | 1 |

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nTVcX1VZNg3DpjFScezgYv/0)

My question is how can I delete the pattern (1,2) and (2,1) with one query based on ID 2. Also if I had lets say another pattern like (67, 2) and (2, 67), how would I delete those patterns?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's ID 2 - there is no id column in the table..

Comment: What if it is only one value `1,2` or `2, 67` should those rows be deleted ?

Comment: @P.Salmon as mentioned before,  user_connections is a junction table, user_from and user_to are FK of the users table. That being said ID 2 is user 2.

Comment: @ErgestBasha The logic behind this junction table is,  if id1 sends a request to id2, in this case, that will be a pending request. The request will be considered approved only if id2 accepts the request which will give the pattern of (id1, id2) and (id2, id1) as shown in the table.

what I want to achieve is to delete an approved request, in my case that would be the following pattern (1, 2) and (2, 1) or it could be (2, 67) and (67, 2).  So I need to query user based on ID (1,2) or (2,67) to delete one of the pattern. I hope It's clear. Thank's again

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. I just need to use WHERE IN as follow:

```
DELETE FROM user_connections
WHERE (user_from, user_to) in ((1, 2), (2, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a user table with an ID linked to the 2 columns you describe here. A request like this could do the job :

```
DELETE uc
FROM user_connections uc
INNER JOIN user u
    ON u.id = uc.user_from
    OR u.id = uc.user_to
WHERE u.id = 2;
```